# How to show 1 value from 2 values in combobox xaml?

Tags: xaml, combobox, silverlight-5.0

Hi I have a ComboBox with show 2 values name and code I want that when I press the drop down
in the ComboBox show the 2 values but when I select from the drop down I want the code 
only return to combo box 
then the name return in other TextBox.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding StoreList,Mode=TwoWay}" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Name="ItemAutoComplete"
          SelectedItem="{Binding TransactionHeader.StorePerRow,Mode=TwoWay}"
          Margin="0,0,105,6"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
          IsEnabled="{Binding TransactionHeader.inter, Mode=TwoWay }"
          SelectedValue="iserial"
          Grid.Row="2"
          Height="44">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />                         
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding ENAME}"></TextBlock>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding code}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I want to return the ename in text box

and show the code only when I choose from list

Answer (score 0):

Bind the Text-Property of TextBox to the SelectedItem of your ComboBox like so

```
<TextBox Text={Binding SelectedItem.ENAME, ElementName=ItemAutoComplete}/>
```

This will display the value of the property `ENAME` of the Item that is selected in your ComboBox.

Comment: thanks it work but i want to return the code only in the Combobox any idea

Comment: Just remove the `TextBlock` that displays the `ename` in the `ComboBox` template then ...